# Multiple log with different settings with log4net and autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, log4net, autofac, autofac-module

I'm making a small web application by using `ASP.Net` Framework with `log4net` and `Autofac 4.0`

My application has to have multiple logging instance with different settings for each of them, i.e: `FileLogger`, `DatabaseLogger`, ...

I'm using log4net module for [autofac](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/examples/log4net.html) :

Can anyone help me to solve this problem please?
Thank you,

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve? And what have you tried?

Comment: there are some controllers I want to write log information to file, there are some I want to write log information to database. Therefore, I need multiple log instance.

Comment: You should update your question with the info @Peter asked about. Also, [have you read the docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial here you can get a basic turial. however for more help you should specify your question